# Fastest one-liner way to check indexOf Object (not String) in array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, optimization, enumeration

Underscore's `_.indexOf` method looks like this:

```
var nativeIndexOf = Array.prototype.indexOf;

_.indexOf = function(array, item, isSorted) {
  if (array == null) return -1;
  var i, l;
  if (isSorted) {
    i = _.sortedIndex(array, item);
    return array[i] === item ? i : -1;
  }
  if (nativeIndexOf && array.indexOf === nativeIndexOf) return array.indexOf(item);
  for (i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) if (i in array && array[i] === item) return i;
  return -1;
};
```

Toward the bottom of that method, it tries to use the native `indexOf` implementation, otherwise it compares the two with the identity operator `===`.

The identity operator `===` works for primitive objects like these:

```
console.log("asdf" === "asdf"); // true
console.log(1 === 1); // true
console.log(1 === 1.0); // true
console.log(null === null); // true
console.log(undefined === undefined); // true
```

But it obviously doesn't work for two `Object` instances, even if they have the same properties and values:

```
console.log({} === {}); // false
console.log({} == {}); // false
var o = {};
console.log(o === o); // true
```

This makes the `indexOf` method not work if the items in an array are of `Object` type.

Question is, what's the most optimized way to find the index of an `Object` in an array in JavaScript.  One way is to `JSON.stringify(o)` every item, which doesn't make sense performance wise.  Another is to call `toString()` for every item (if `toString()` returns something other than `[object Object]`, like ObjectID does in the node-native-mongodb module for node.js, returning an id string).  A third solution, probably the most common, is to iterate over each key in each object.  None of these are really ideal.

What is the recommended solution to this problem?

Comment: If two objects are not identical, I don't think there is a better way to find out if they're equal than comparing all their fields and their values. Well, one optimization could be to check if their prototypes are identical and then if their own fields match.

Comment: Of course, the previous holds depending on your definition of identity. If I have two objects: `a = {x: 0}; a.__proto__ = {y: 1};` and `b = {x: 0; y: 1}`, do you consider them identical?

Comment: What the best solution is will really depend on the specific use case. If a "GetId()" method can be added easily (i.e. each object already has a unique ID), that approach will most likely be the best idea. Underscore's `_.isEqual()` is a good choice if you want to compare objects.

Comment: answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6689666/908879