# Sort nested array of objects at any level in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have some array of objects, some objects can have some array again at any level, So I want all the objects in alphabetical order.

Ex:

```
{
    "b": [
        {
            "pqr": [
                {
                    "z": "s",
                    "t": "t"
                }
            ],
            "c": "d",
            "q": "c"
        },
        {
            "m": "h",
            "b": "g"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the output as

```
{
    "b": [
        {
            "c": "d",
            "pqr": [
                {
                    "t": "t",
                    "z": "s"
                }
            ],
            "q": "c"
        },
        {
            "b": "g"
            "m": "h",
        }
    ]
}
```

after `JSON.stringify()`, so basically I want the sorted order at any level, arrays can also have objects which also needs to be in sorted order, I have gone through other Stack Overflow questions, but did not find this.
I was trying using the below code (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28565621/1364965, but this code does not solve my problem), but does not seem to work, recursion code does not seem to work,

```
function sortObject(obj) {
   var tmpArr = [];
    var tmpKeys = [];
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        var objLen = obj.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < objLen; i++) {
            if (obj[i] instanceof Array) {
               tmpArr[i] = sortObject(obj[i]);
            } else {
                for (key in obj[i]) {
                    tmpKeys.push(key);
                }  
                tmpKeys.sort();
            }
        }
    }

    var temp = {};
    var keys = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        keys.push(key);  
    }
    keys.sort();
    for (var index in keys) {
        temp[keys[index]] = sortObject(obj[keys[index]]);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

How it can be achieved?

Comment: Objects do not maintain order. It's basically an unordered hash map. What it means is that - you cannot sort them.

Comment: I think the OP wants to take that object and sort the output to a string which is possible. This seems like a problem set question though. What have you tried so far rather than just searching for an answer?

Comment: You can do this technically (in *string* format, not using vanilla JavaScript objects)...but it will be very hard. You'll basically have to implement Python's OrderedDict and then write your own `toString` method. I hope you're patient. :)

Comment: @JasonCust , I have updated the code which I tried, but there is some problem with recursion it seems...

Comment: @zerkms They're not specified to, but the actual implementations might be stable under enough circumstances to get something working. :P

Comment: @JeremyBanks or one might just switch to a more suitable data structure for the task. Always better than to rely on something unreliable.

Comment: @zerkms That's certainly true, but I would enjoy reading a hacky solution if one were possible possible.

Comment: @JeremyBanks actually for me chrome `41.0.2272.118 m` returns the given structure "sorted" automatically. So you don't need to do anything. Unreliable - yes, hacky - yes. Where is my cookie? :-D

Comment: @zerkms I meant a complete solution to this question. :P The author already has some code that tries to take advantage of this, but it doesn't work. One would need to figure out why.

Comment: @JeremyBanks instead of debugging spaghetti I prefer to implement my own http://pastebin.com/7ZK7CBNK :-) That's how I would do that if I was serious about the question.