# How to order responses in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When retrieving data from my database the Schema's order is not maintained and the response is not in the format I need. I need the response to be the same as the Schema, the response I get is in this order:

### Response

```
[
 {
  "comments": [],
  "_id": "5ede3608c9cd033744641188",
  "title": "Book 1",
  "__v": 0
 },
 {
  "comments": [],
  "_id": "5ede360cc9cd033744641189",
  "title": "Book 2",
  "__v": 0
 }
]
```

### Book Schema:

```
const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    commentCount: Number,
    comments: [String]
  }, {collection: 'fcclibrary'});

  const Book = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);
```

### POST request

```
.post(function (req, res){
      let title = req.body.title;
      let newBook = new Book({
        title: title
      });
      newBook.save((err, book) => {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(book);
          res.json({title: book.title, id: book.id});
        }
      })
    })
```

### GET request

```
app.route('/api/books')
    .get(function (req, res){
      Book.find({}, (err, found) => {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log(found);
          res.json(found);
        }
      })
```

How can I preserve order of my Schema when retrieving it from the DB? I have already tried **`retainKeyOrder: true`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you are using Mongoose 4.6.4 or above ([Mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/guide.html#retainKeyOrder))
It's odd that the retainKeyOrder did not work for you (never tried it myself but please double check)

In addition here are a few StackOverflow posts that discusses about a very similar case as yours:

[Sort Keys in Response Object from Mongoose in ExpressJS and NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903281/sort-keys-in-response-object-from-mongoose-in-expressjs-and-nodejs/51904520)

[Using a "replacer" to create the output order that you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40646557/3263659)