# How do I filter the unique objects from an array if the filter key can have any type of value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript

```
interface FormValues {
    key: string;
    value: any;
}

const array: FormValues[] = [
    {
        key: 'A',
        value: 1 // number
    },
    {
        key: 'A',
        value: 1 // number
    },
    {
        key: 'A',
        value: 'str' // string
    },
    {
        key: 'C',
        value: { a: 1, b: '2' } // object
    },
    {
        key: 'C',
        value: ['a','2'] // array
    },
    {
        key: 'C',
        value: ['a','2'] // array
    }
    {
        key: 'B',
        value: true // boolean
    }
]
```

I want to filter the objects based on field `value`, which can have a value of any type.

I tried to do it like this; my solution is not working for nested object checks.

```
const key = 'value';
const arrayUniqueByKey = [...new Map(array.map(item => [item[key], item])).values()];
```

output :

```
    [{
        key: 'A',
        value: 1 // number
    },
    {
        key: 'A',
        value: 'str' // string
    },
    {
        key: 'C',
        value: { a: 1, b: '2' } // object
    },
    {
        key: 'C',
        value: ['a','2'] // array
    },
    {
        key: 'B',
        value: true // boolean
    }]
```

Comment: How does the `filter` value look like? What does the `Map` code in the question have to do with filter? Please add all the inputs and the expected output

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: What do you mean *"it didn't work out"*? Did it throw an error or did it just not produce the result you wanted? Shouldn't `const array: FormValues` be `const array: FormValues[]`?

Comment: update the question @gorak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide what makes two distinct objects "equal".  In JavaScript, all built-in comparisons of objects (which includes arrays) are [by reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#comparing_objects).  That means `['a','2'] === ['a','2']` is `false` because two distinct array objects exist, despite having the same contents.  See [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects) for more information.

I will take the approach that you would like two values to be considered equal if they serialize to the same value via a modified version of [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) where the order of property keys are guaranteed to be the same (so `{a: 1, b: 2}` and `{b: 2, a: 1}` will be equal no matter how those are stringified).  I use a version from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53593328/2887218) to do so:

```
function JSONstringifyOrder(obj: any, space?: number) {
    var allKeys: string[] = [];
    var seen: Record<string, null | undefined> = {};
    JSON.stringify(obj, function (key, value) {
        if (!(key in seen)) {
            allKeys.push(key); seen[key] = null;
        }
        return value;
    });
    allKeys.sort();
    return JSON.stringify(obj, allKeys, space);
}
```

And now I can use that to make the keys of your `Map`:

```
const arrayUniqueByKey = [...new Map(array.map(
    item => [JSONstringifyOrder(item[key]), item]
)).values()];
```

And you can verify that it behaves as you'd like:

```
console.log(arrayUniqueByKey);
/* [{
  "key": "A",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "key": "A",
  "value": "str"
}, {
  "key": "C",
  "value": {
    "a": 1,
    "b": "2"
  }
}, {
  "key": "C",
  "value": [
    "a",
    "2"
  ]
}, {
  "key": "B",
  "value": true
}] */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsoFsBqcA2ArhAM7IDeAUMjcgNYQCeAXMiWFKAOYDc1tANwLFWcEIz4BfSpQToQ7ZHChQ4LNJlzDSAbQC6yALzId-GlVqX6TVgHIAgrYA0Zq0KIRWARmQB6X8gghFgARtCuki6WFlY0DOoOzq6W7iLIPv6BwWFQEVG0MbHxdo75sameyLbsULZ+ATXcea6FVsVVAMJJsTQVrORK3k7IIXYATHWS9cjoIQBWEAhgzdHJtO22XWVu2qw6tnDOVRMGmcqqjCsFa3E2nd09fSYHR7Yn0+dqV+Y31gkAQg9yrtkBxiNMQuh0PgIGIIpQ9DIYIQQEtgPJkAApADKAHkAHKNEBcYAwRi4qAAE2gAApZnNROJhiQAA6ICAAflYQVC0AAlBRXEIoEp8PgANJMEisIlcfRGEx6PgpZRsCAQECsABKi0wlIAPLLhkExcgAD7IFHUmCgCCUgB8CvIkmVtBxBIAdLLSYw6fNhsjUWB0SBkDT4sMKgLWpZSWGAIThpjIUBqjV86O-SwECVSj0swgkAAWScYfJ4aZAOniBmMJvwrti0h6yCgEDAhCgoYqjeQknLrhzksYJC9mDANIHljbHa7WLx+K9HG4Pr9c2GQ6lzLZSAH0lk8kU8QVtgqtj4B4UYCUKjUAFUQMAAI7Ef6MYcKnQe78gCAAd2QABZOAWRpT5GA9LAQJpVxgEgLAjEdHR3UJZdiR9ClqSgGk4IgLBqyYPQ+WGXCsERDMPQqEhJyVGQ5AUaEIA9fB0C4MDb0YB9n1fd8mAHXwACoTBiAAieIRNYET7BE-IRIqCT0koSJBRoMSmAUqSZP4OTtA0moRKU4ZRPEySOi01T5P6VwRLgBSvG2ESQg0sYDJoaRlOM9TTPM5AdI8BTTEsGyfNUlz+ERDztJM3z-h8vziAUsEICUgwBN8SggA)

Answer (score 0):

This will combine any duplicate keys, creating a new property `values` to hold the array of combined values (from like keys).

```js
const array = [{key: 'A', value: 1},{key: 'A', value: 'str'},{key: 'C', value: { a: 1, b: '2'}},{key: 'B',value: true}]

const arrayUniqueByKey = [array.reduce((b, a) => {
  let f = b.findIndex(c => c.key === a.key)
  if (f === -1) return [...b, a];
  else {
    b[f].values = [...[b[f].value], a.value];
    return b
  }
}, [])];

console.log(arrayUniqueByKey)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. OP wants to filter by the value field, and there are two objects with `"key": "A"` with different values, so both should be in your output.

Comment: @MarksASP - thanks, that makes more sense. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) combined with [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and finaly get the `result` array of values with [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
const array = [{key: 'A',value: 1,},{key: 'A',value: 1,},{key: 'A',value: 'str',},{key: 'C',value: { a: 1, b: '2' },},{key: 'C',value: ['a', '2'],},{key: 'C',value: ['a', '2'],},{key: 'B',value: true}]

const result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, c) => ((a[JSON.stringify(c)] = c), a), {}))

console.log(result)
```