# Extending {} (an Object) in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, extends

So I am trying to extend the object class. The reason why is because I want to write a function called isEqual

```
isEqual(object: any): boolean {
    return JSON.stringify(this) === JSON.stringify(object);
}
```

I tried to extend Object, but there is no generic type.

I know I could just use a function that takes two arguments and checks it. But I want to learn how to do this in Typescript.

I read on StackOverflow that operator overloading is not possible (because originally I want to use the == operator to call the function above).

Could someone help me?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It can be done [like this](https://tsplay.dev/m0nonw), but [**you should not**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/2887218). It's almost universally considered poor practice to mess with native prototypes.  Does that answer your question?  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Please mention @jcalz in your comment if you reply or I won't be notified)

Comment: @jcalz or [at least](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572) like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFmQbwChllgBnAUQEcBXOAGwAoB7LHMALmVe1wEou6Zs3oQ4IANyEAvoQy8wAOgAmEGKAgAFKMwAO0MAE9G89ot06wzI-oA0yAOTlqdeg-tESANwY0ILNlwuHnY+AmISZCgIMBooEGQAKQBlVAA5RTIwKFAAc2AYYzAAC3IwgF5KpNSMrJyQfMKAhT4pEmlbCIRmEHVcuLh0US5sv07pVsJCbpAs7gBGZHKCZDgueft0LgAiMAB3Zm3kaSkZueYAJiWVreRdg+37NeRFk+meshEIRXpmXJZ5opnLQGCwLnxWsgAPRQ5DwehkCBAA)

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for your answer. Also thanks for the explainer why I should not do this.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking to add an `isEqual()` method to all instances of [the global `Object` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).  In JavaScript this can be done by adding the method to `Object.prototype` and all instances of objects will [inherit the method automatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Before I say how to do it, it is almost universally considered **a bad idea** to modify native prototypes like that.  See [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/2887218) for the official SO answer about that.  But briefly: Think of `Object.prototype` as [common property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commons) that needs to be shared by everyone.  If you start making changes to it, and other code doesn't expect those changes, then that code can fail to run properly.  Conversely, some other code could potentially make changes that make *your* changes fail to run properly.

The naïve way of adding a method to `Object.prototype`, like `Object.prototype.isEqual = ...` or `Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'isEqual', {value(...){...}})` will end up putting `isEqual` as an [enumerable property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) of all objects, meaning that a [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) would suddenly show `"isEqual"` as a key for every possible object everywhere.

The official advice here is **don't do it**.

---

If you still want to do it (e.g., maybe you are doing this with code nobody else will need to interact with, so the only person potentially harmed by this is you), then here's how.  TypeScript supports [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to allow additions to existing interfaces:

```
interface Object {
  isEqual(object: object): boolean;
}
```

If you write that, the compiler will now expect that all `Object`s have an `isEqual()` method.  (If your code is in a module, you will need to wrap that in a `declare global { }` block, known as [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation)).

Of course you still have to implement it:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'isEqual', {
  value(object: object) {
    return JSON.stringify(this) === JSON.stringify(object);
  },
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false // <-- we don't want to mess with for...in loops
});
```

Here I've used [the `Object.defineProperty()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) so that we can explicitly prevent the method name from being enumerable.

And now you can verify that it works as desired:

```
interface Foo { a: number, b: string };
const o1: Foo = { a: 1, b: "two" };
const o2: Foo = { b: "two", a: 1 };
console.log(o1.isEqual(o2)); // false
```

The `o1.isEqual(o2)` compiles with no error, and when you run it, it uses your `isEqual()` method, and returns `false` as expected.  (You *did* expect `false`, right?  See [sort object properties and JSON.stringify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16167581/2887218) if you didn't.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFmQbwChllgBnAUQEcBXOAGwAoB7LHMALmVe1wEou6Zs3oQ4IANyEAvoQy8wAOgAmEGKAgAFKMwAO0MAE9G89ot06wzI-oA0yAOTlqdeg-tESANwY0ILNlwuHnY+AmISZCgIMBooEGQAKQBlVAA5RTIwKFAAc2AYYzAAC3IwgF5KpNSMrJyQfMKAhT4pEmlbCIRmEHVcuLh0US5sv06SCBAaAFtoQeHkeHoyCBlWwkJQSFhEFAAxYQJkOC4p6fRoe3QuOrzkaSlukCzuAEYuA+ZkcqOT5FerlwAERgADuzCB90ePRezAATB9Dj98MhrsgQeCgfY-q8oYQnmQRBBFPRmLkWK9FM5aAwWHC+K1kAB6JmLBgrDZAA)